# Branch.io params is always empty when my app is on background (opened)

Tags: android, branch.io

I have a pretty straight forward setting, setup

- my intent filters for my main activity on the manifest
- singleTask mode for all my activities (it just have two)

My app have two entry points: one the intent filter will call my MainActivity which start the branch session return the values on the referringParams and I go to the SecondActivity, everyone is happy

the another entry point is the launcher, when I click open the MainActivity do somethhing different because intent.data is empty and Go to SecondActivity, the problem is as follows, after the app is in the SecondActivity and the app goes background (e.g. touch home button) and then tap on some link the MainActivity is launched intent.data is not empty there's a valid url but when my callback is called I got referringParams empty `{}`

I dont know what is wrong with this. i have spend some hours without success

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();

    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener(){
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // here referringParams is a empty {} object
            } else {
                Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    this.setIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what processing you are doing in your Main Activity. The use case you mentioned, should return the Branch link parameters correctly,

1. If you have the intent filters and the launchMode of the MainActivity, correctly defined
2. You are overriding the onNewIntent() method in your MainActivity (which I can see from the code snippet you shared)

I created a sample app, which is uploaded [here](https://github.com/amruta-d/Sample-Android-App). If you follow the test case you mentioned with this app(i.e. App is backgrounded with the SecondActivity), clicking on a Branch link returns the link parameters correctly.